# How to send localized notifications using the Java Admin SDK version of Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Does anyone know if the Java Admin SDK FCM module supports localization?

According to the docs, at least for the REST interface,  we can specify body_loc_key and title_loc_key instead of body and title Strings which will then be localized on the received devices.

It doesn't look like there is any way to do this using the Java SDK, although it seems unlikely though as this must be a common requirement.

Comment: Have you tried custom key value pairs for the APS dictionary (Apple) using : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Aps.Builder#putCustomData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object) and for Android using the sdk value of addBodyLocalizationArg: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidNotification.Builder#addBodyLocalizationArg(java.lang.String) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of several nested builders, yeah finally we got to the working solution.

https://dev.to/davebrown1975/localised-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-ecn